# Removing a character from custom natbib .bst output

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Good evening,

I'm having a hard time trying to modify a custom .bst provided by my university. The actual output looks like this:

```
Büring, Daniel. (1992). Linking. Dekomposition - Theta-Rollen - Argumentstruktur. In: Vater, Heinz; Lenerz, Jürgen (Hgg.), Kölner Linguistische Arbeiten 27, Hürth-Efferen: Gabel.
Diesing, Molly. (1990). Verb Movement and the Subject Position in Yiddish. Natural Language and Linguistic Theory 8, 1. 41–79. 
Diesing, Molly. (1997). Yiddish VP Order and the Typology of Object Movement.Natural Language and Linguistic Theory 15, 2. 369–427.
Fleischer, Jürg. (2010). Relativsätze im Deutschen und Jiddischen. In: Dammel, Antje; Kürschner, Sebastian; Nübling, Damaris (Hgg.), Kontrastive Germanistische Linguistik, Teilband 1, 145–169. Hildesheim: Olms. 
Fleischer, Jürg; Schäfer, Lea. (2012). Der Kasus nach Präposition in westjiddischen Quellen des (langen) 19. Jahrhunderts. In: Aptroot, Marion; Gal-Ed, Efrat; Gruschka, Roland et al. (Hgg.), Jiddistik heute. Yiddish Studies Today, Band 1, 415–436. Düsseldorf: d|u|p.
```

This is what I'd like to achieve is removing the period after the author's names, i.e. the entries should look like this:

```
Büring, Daniel (1992). Linking. Dekomposition - Theta-Rollen - Argumentstruktur. In: Vater, Heinz; Lenerz, Jürgen (Hgg.), Kölner Linguistische Arbeiten 27, Hürth-Efferen: Gabel.
Diesing, Molly (1990). Verb Movement and the Subject Position in Yiddish. Natural Language and Linguistic Theory 8, 1. 41–79. 
Diesing, Molly (1997). Yiddish VP Order and the Typology of Object Movement.Natural Language and Linguistic Theory 15, 2. 369–427.
Fleischer, Jürg (2010). Relativsätze im Deutschen und Jiddischen. In: Dammel, Antje; Kürschner, Sebastian; Nübling, Damaris (Hgg.), Kontrastive Germanistische Linguistik, Teilband 1, 145–169. Hildesheim: Olms. 
Fleischer, Jürg; Schäfer, Lea (2012). Der Kasus nach Präposition in westjiddischen Quellen des (langen) 19. Jahrhunderts. In: Aptroot, Marion; Gal-Ed, Efrat; Gruschka, Roland et al. (Hgg.), Jiddistik heute. Yiddish Studies Today, Band 1, 415–436. Düsseldorf: d|u|p.
```

Sounds easy enough, right? Well, having invested a few days in modifying the .bst (and having gotten some pretty good results so far), I find it impossible to make that desired change. So, here I am.

This seems to be the respective function in the .bst, I guess:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ { 
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      duplicate$ #1 > 
        { "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" }
        { "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" } 
      if$
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "; "
                  * t *                  
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't 
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

I do not have the slightest clue where the period comes from (and I have to admit, that the language isn't really intuitive). This function

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }
```

and that function

```
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

are used, but both do not seem related to that particular problem. The output is generated in this (or in a similar) function, which also doesn't seem to be too related.

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.bpartvolume output
      format.number.series output
      add.comma
      format.addendum output
      format.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.url output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

It would really be great, If someone could find a solution. Which probably is simple if you fully understand the language. Which I really don't, at all.

If you need further informations about anything, I'd be glad to provide everything needed.

Thanks to all of you in advance, for this site has already proven to be helpful so many times.

(Just in case: the complete .bst can be found here: [Custom .bst under construction](http://think-strange.de/thesis.bst))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of problem is not easy to determine, as you've noted. It arises in the function `output.nonnull`, which is called by `output.check`, which is called by `inproceedings` on the line that says

```
format.authors "author" output.check
```

I suggest you do the following:

- Find the function `output.nonnull`. (I believe it starts on line 69.)
- In this function, change the lines

  ```
      { output.state before.all =
          'write$
          { add.period$ " " * write$ }
        if$
      }
  ```

  to

  ```
      { output.state before.all =
          'write$
          { " " * write$ }
        if$
      }
  ```

If you apply this modification, you will need to add a period ("full stop", "`.`") at the end of the `pages` fields (if present) for entries of type `@inproceedings`, `@inbook`, etc. I trust this trade-off is acceptable. (A more complete solution, ie., one which doesn't require modifying some `pages` fields, might be based by running the `makebst` utility to create a bespoke style file from scratch. However, since the style file you're working with has already been modified extensively to suit your specific needs, starting over entirely with a `makebst` run may actually be more work to you, since you'd have to (re)apply all of your previous modifications.)

A full MWE (the modified version of your file `thesis.bst` is called `mythesis.bst`; the `filecontents` package is used to create the bib file `zzz.bib` on the fly):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{zzz.bib}
@string{ _dup = "d$\vert$u$\vert$p" }
@string{ _nllt= "Natural Language and Linguistic Theory" }
@incollection{yyy,
  author = "B{\"u}ring, Daniel",
  year   = 1992,
  title  = "Linking. Dekomposition -- Theta-Rollen -- Argumentstruktur",
  editor = "Vater, Heinz and Lenerz, J{\"u}rgen",
  booktitle = "K{\"o}lner Linguistische Arbeiten 27",
  publisher = "Gabel",
  address   = "H{\"u}rth-Efferen",
}
@article{d:1990,
  author  = "Diesing, Molly",
  year    = 1990,
  title   = "Verb Movement and the Subject Position in Yiddish",
  journal = _nllt,
  volume  = 8, 
  number  = 1,
  pages   = "41-79",
}
@article{d:1997, 
  author  = "Diesing, Molly",
  year    = 1997,
  title   = "Yiddish VP Order and the Typology of Object Movement",
  journal = _nllt,
  volume  = 15,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = "369-427",
}
@inproceedings{fl:2010,
  author  = "Fleischer, J{\"u}rg",
  year    = 2010,
  title   = "Relativs{\"a}tze im Deutschen und Jiddischen",
  editor  = "Dammel, Antje and K{\"u}rschner, Sebastian and N{\"u}bling, Damaris",
  booktitle= "Kontrastive Germanistische Linguistik",
  partvolume = 1,
  pages   = "145-169.", 
  address = "Hildesheim",
  publisher= "Olms",
} 
@incollection{uuu,
  author  = "Fleischer, J{\"u}rg and Sch{\"a}fer, Lea",
  year    = 2012,
  title   = "Der Kasus nach Pr{\"a}position in westjiddischen Quellen des (langen) 19.\ Jahrhunderts",
  editor  = "Aptroot, Marion and Gal-Ed, Efrat and Gruschka, Roland and Neuberg, Simon",
  booktitle = "Jiddistik heute. Yiddish Studies Today",
  volume    = 1,
  pages     = "415-436.",
  address   = "D{\"u}sseldorf",
  publisher = _dup,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{mythesis}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was fast and brilliant, thanks a lot. I just had to add one line to FUNCTION {inproceedings} and voilà. 

And: Yes, it would be much tidyer to redo the whole style, for there some choices are questionable at best (e.g. either.or.check for author and editor). But until then, this will work just fine!